# Best practice to create Python class with hardcoded dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pyre-check

I am new to Python. I have a function like below which returns a dictionary.

```
def get_my_class_object(self, input):
    return {
            "foo": {"test": {}}, // this is hard-coded
            "var": "FIRST" // real code computes var using the input
        }
```

I'd like to define a class for the return type so I can enable the type using Pyre.
What is the best practice to create a python class for above structure?

I tried below class and changed the function signature to return MyClassObject.

```
class MyClassObject(NamedTuple):
    foo: Dict
    var: str
```

```
def get_my_class_object(self, input) -> MyClassObject:
// create MyClassObject from input and return the object
```

But `Dict` is not allowed by Pyre as it is too generic. I can't change `"foo": {"test": {}}` due to backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you might be able to do in this case. Without any context, it is quite hard to know what might be best for you.

But, using a more specific type-hint might work:

Here, instead of a `NamedTuple`, it might also be best to use a [`DataClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

```py
@dataclass
class MyData:
    foo: dict[str, dict]
    var: str
```

Here, `foo` is typed as `dict[str, dict]` which may be specific enough for Pyre. If you know what the type of the "innermost" dictionary should be, you can type-hint that here too. For example, let's say the innermost dictionary will eventually be used to map a string to an int, you could type-hint it as:

```py
dict[str, dict[str, int]]
```

It may also be more clear to use *type aliases*. Check out the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases-1) for more info, but that could look something like:

```py
# Defining type aliases
TestData = dict[str, int]  # Here I'm assuming this inner dictionary maps strings to ints
Test = dict[str, TestData]


@dataclass
class MyData:
    foo: Test  # here we can just use the alias to make the code cleaner
    var: str
```

You might need to change the names of these to better fit your purpose.

Also note, I'm using python 3.9+ syntax for type-hinting, if you are using a lower version, you'll need to import the `Dict` type from the `typing` module.

Comment: Thanks for comment. If `foo` is always hard-coded with dictionary `{"test": {}}`, what is the best way to init `foo` ?

Comment: Using a dataclass, you could do something like:
`foo: Test = field(default_factory=lambda: {"test": {}})`
Check out the [field documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field)

However, at this point, it might be easiest to use a regular class with an `__init__` method that sets the value. In _most_ cases, classes are cheap – if they make things easier, don't be afraid to use them.